# Is there a way to pause an execution of a workflow?

Tags: google-workflows

Is there a way to pauses and resumes a workflow programmatically through the REST API? For instance, I would like to be able to submit a personal time off request from an app, the app creates and triggers a workflow. The workflow sends a notification to the manager for approval and the workflow execution is paused while waiting for the manager's approval. Once the manager approves the request, it calls the workflow API to resumes the execution of the workflow.

From the documentation, there's an option to put the workflow to sleep and I can use it to periodically check for the request's status but this incurs additional cost because there's no idea when the manager is going to approve the request.

https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update 2021-10-05:*

[Waiting for an HTTP callback](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/creating-callback-endpoints) is now supported:

```
    - create_callback:
        call: events.create_callback_endpoint
        args:
            http_callback_method: POST # can be GET, PUT, ...
        result: callback_details
    # Send the callback URL somewhere for another service to call
    - await_callback:
        call: events.await_callback
        args:
            callback: ${callback_details}
            timeout: 1800 # optional, in seconds
        result: callback_request
```

---

*Original response*

The ability to wait for an HTTP webhook callback during a workflow execution is planned. (I'm the Workflows PM.)

Until then, you're right that the best solution is to poll for a flag (Firestore works well for this) using `sleep`.

Comment: I also need this feature in Google Cloud Workflows. How can I know when this feature is available? Looks like AWS Step Functions can achieve this by "Wait for a Callback with the Task Token". Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token

Comment: When the feature is publicly available, it will be announced to this group: https://groups.google.com/g/workflows-announce.

You can also request to join the Workflows Insiders group, which is granted early access to pre-release features: https://forms.gle/28CrZ3wxXucZuzVw6

Comment: @KrisBraun I recognize that you can't commit timing in the comments of SO, but can you provide a target timing or where this feature is prioritized on your backlog? We've got some use cases that would benefit from this feature, but might go a different way if you think it's not likely to come before Q2 2021.

Comment: @NickYap I can confirm we're actively working on this feature and will launch it first in private preview. Could you apply to the Workflows Insiders program so you'll have an opportunity to join the preview? forms.gle/28CrZ3wxXucZuzVw6 When I see your application come through, I'll reach out learn more about your use case and share more about our plans.

Comment: It's out now ! :-) https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/introducing-workflows-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your use-case, but I guess you can only choose to execute the workflow once the manager has approved.

As you know there are 2 parts the first part creates the workflow.
As it is in https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/rest/v1beta/projects.locations.workflows/create api for example.
Or you can look at https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/creating-updating-workflow.

That does not execute the workflow it just creates it. So it can be executed at a later stage.

To execute the workflow, there is this Api https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/executions/rest/v1beta/projects.locations.workflows.executions/create
OR see https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/executing-workflow

Also when executing the workflow you can pass in parameters if needed.

Then If I understand the pricing correctly from https://cloud.google.com/workflows#section-9 it seems they only charge you per step executed.

Sorry, I have been through those docs a fair amount I did not see an "option to put the workflow to sleep", Could you link those docs by any chance?

Comment: In the workflow syntax document, there's a sleep step:

https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax

Answer (score 1):

We are talking about two separate workflows here. There is no reason to engineer with pause or not.

1. Initiate and go up until you fire the approval process.
2. After approval, trigger a new workflow that does the rest of the steps.

Comment: That would works but from a business process standpoint, it is viewed as a single workflow which is to approve a particular request. It just happens that one of its steps requires manual input. If I were to split it into multiple workflows, then I would need to keep track which set of workflows belongs to a single business process.

Comment: You could easily do that with a session param, that you pass to your workflow, and keep it from one step to the other.